# can't make the data for the id in each line goes to the form to see the rest of the database

Tags: javascript, laravel, crud

---

**Title:** Display Form Data for Specific ID When Clicking a Button in Laravel

**Question:**

I'm working on a Laravel project, and I'm trying to make a button open a form with data specific to the clicked item. I have a table that displays donor information, and each row has a "Details" button. When this button is clicked, I want to open a modal that displays a form with the details of the corresponding donor.

Here's what I have so far:

In my `DonorController`, I have an `index` method that retrieves all donors and passes them to the view, and I'm using a route to access this method.

```php
public function index($donorId = null)
{
    $donors = Donor::all();
    return view('CEST.Home.Home', compact('donors', 'donorId'));
}
```

In my view, I'm displaying the donors in a table and using JavaScript to open the modal when the "Details" button is clicked.

```
@foreach($donors as $donor)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $donor->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $donor->donor_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $donor->address }}</td>
        <td>{{ $donor->donor_request_date }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="custom-button" onclick="openModal('{{ $donor->id }}'); this.classList.toggle('clicked')">Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And in my JavaScript, I'm trying to open the modal with the correct donor's details.

```js
function openModal(donorId) {
    const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    const modalIframe = document.getElementById('modal-iframe');
    const routeUrl = `/home-form/${donorId}`;
    modalIframe.src = routeUrl;
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    void modal.offsetWidth;
    modal.style.opacity = '1';
    modal.querySelector('.modal-content').style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)';
}
```

However, I'm struggling to link the button to the form with the same donor's data. How can I modify my code to achieve this? Do I need to create a new controller method and route for displaying the form with specific donor data?

Any guidance on the best practices to implement this feature in Laravel would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to display each donor's data in a popup when the user clicks the details button. You have two choices, firstly to get whole these data beforehand in the index method and show them directly when the user clicks the Details button. Secondly, send a request to show API each time the user clicks the Details button. I recommend second choice and will provide codes for it:
routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/donors', 'DonorController@index')->name('donors.index');
Route::get('/donor/{id}', 'DonorController@show')->name('donor.show');
```

DonorController:

```
public function index()
{
    $donors = Donor::all();
    return view('CEST.Home.Home', compact('donors'));
}

public function show($id)
{
    $donor = Donor::findOrFail($id);
    return view('CEST.Home.DonorDetails', compact('donor'));
}
```

add the empty modal to your view for updating by JS:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div id="donorDetails"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then update your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".custom-button").on('click', function() {
        const donorId = $(this).data('donor-id');
        fetchDonorDetails(donorId);
    });
    
    $(".close").on('click', function() {
        $("#myModal").hide();
    });
});

function fetchDonorDetails(donorId) {
    $.get(`/donor/${donorId}`, function(data) {
        $("#donorDetails").html(data);
        $("#myModal").show();
    });
}
```

details button:

```
<button class="custom-button" data-donor-id="{{ $donor->id }}">Details</button>
```

these are the simple code that handles what you want. You can improve and modify it for your project.